# R' Hirsch on the Sign of the Rainbow

Tags: sources-mekorot, parashat-noach, samson-raphael-hirsch, rainbows

can anyone find me the exact words of r' hirsch, when he comments that...

the rainbow is one of the many אותות such as shabbos, tefillin, and circumcision- all of which are designed to keep alive and fresh the great teachings which Hashem gave man. The rainbow is the eternal sign that no matter how bleak the future may seem, Hashem will lead mankind to its ultimate goal.

quoted from Artscroll (schottenstein edition), parshas noach 9:8-17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is found in his commentary to Genesis (chapter one):

> כמעט ואין "אות" ו"מועד" במקרא - אלא בתחום חיי האדם השכליים והמוסריים. "אותות" הן תופעות הגלויות לחושים, - המביאות לידי מחשבה או מעוררות את המחשבה...ומכאן "המועדים": זמני קודש שה' קבעם, - וישראל על ידי קידוש החודש - להיוועד בהם לפני ה'. ואכן, גופי השמים המאירים על הארץ הם "אותות" וגם "מועדים". הם אותות לאדם דרך כלל...כל אלה מספרים כבוד אל משמים...
>   **אולם, המאורות הם "אותות" גם דרך פרט...הם מזכירים ומסמלים את הבטחות ה' ואת ייעודי מצוותיו לעמו**. את הבטחתו הראשונה לאדם ואת מצותו הראשונה לישראל - הנציח ה' בכתב כוכבים. לאנושות המתחדשת על אדמה חדשה הוא **הראה את הקשת בשמים ואמר: "זאת אות הברית אשר הקימותי ביני ובין כל בשר אשר על הארץ"** (בראשית ט, יז)...ובטרם יצא ישראל בדרכו ההיסטורית, הראה למנהיגיו את הלבנה המתחדשת ואמר: "החדש הזה לכם" (שמות יב, ב) - חידוש זה של האור יהיה "דוגמא שלכם". הנה הלבנה מתחדשת תמיד, ואורה מוסיף והולך; **כן תתחדשו גם אתם ותוסיפו טהרה ותקומו לחיים חדשים; כן חדשו את אורכם, קומו ואורו - מכל עלטת מוסר ורוח, מכל חושך אפלת גורל.** הנה זו בשורתכם לעולם: בשורת הגאולה מן הרע ומן החטא, וחידוש הנעורים לקראת חירות וחיים...וכל המועדים האלה תלויים במהלך המאורות, - בחדשי הלבנה ובתקופות החמה. הם מכוונים את מבטנו לטבע ולהיסטוריה כאחד; והם מראים לנו את האל האחד, המנהיג כאחד את הטבע וההיסטוריה. כך היו המאורות "לאותות ולמועדים" - כדי לחנך את האדם ואת ישראל. וגם ייעודם זה תלוי במהלכם הקבוע, שנקבע בידי הבורא; ופקודת ההסמכה של המאורות - "והיו לאותות ולמועדים" - רומזת אפוא לשליחותם ההיסטורית לאדם ולישראל.

Comment: The passage was quite long, so I replaced some with ellipses.

Comment: is there a link that you can post where you found this?

Comment: You are very welcome!! It looks like you can vote now. I got the text from the Bar Ilan database. It is not available online, but a text searchable but not copyable version is, here: https://www.responsa.co.il/home.en-US.aspx. There is also http://hebrewbooks.org/ which has OCRed text, searchable, but not nicely copyable. There is also http://www.sefaria.org/?home but I don't see the R. Hirsch commentary there. @LittleMissFabulous